# I haven't encountered this syntax in Objective C before

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

This is from a book on iphone game development.

```
[((GameState*)viewController.view) Update];
```

"viewController" is an instance of UIViewcontroller, "GameState" is a subclass of UIView, and "Update" is a method of "GameState".  Can you please tell me what is happening. Does this syntax allow the viewController to use the methods of GameState? I apologize if this is a stupid question.

Comment: it is just a simple casting...

Comment: A book that calls a `UIView` subclass `GameState` and uses uppercase for a method name does not seem suitable to teach Objective-C.

Comment: what is wrong with `GameState` ?

Comment: Generally something intended to store state about the program would be a model object. Having a view that does so *probably* means that it's trying to do several things at once that could be separated out.

Answer (score 3):

All that's doing is telling the compiler "hey, viewController.view is actually of type GameState*". It doesn't actually *do* anything to it though, just lets the compiler know so it won't warn about it.

Note that it's entirely legal to lie to the compiler like this, and it will believe you, and not check your work, so it's best to avoid casting if you can. If you cast it to something it isn't, it will crash if you try to use methods it doesn't have.

Answer (score 1):

What's going on here is a C type cast: you are telling the compiler that you know that your `viewController`'s `view` is of type `GameState`, and that you know that it's OK to invoke methods of `GameState` here, even though these methods are not part of the `UIView`'s interface.

Answer (score 1):

Means that viewController's view is casted to a GameState (subclass of UIView) and in this way the compiler does not complain that Update method is invoked.

This has the inconvenience of potentially generating a runtime error so to be safe I will enclose the previous statement in:

```
if ([viewController.view isKindOfClass:[GameState class]])
```